# Sqlite3 crashes from Process on Python 3

Tags: macos, python-3.x, process, sqlite, python-requests

I am trying to initialize my database from from a process but I get return code `-11`, which seems to be segmentation fault.

```py
import requests
import sqlite3
from multiprocessing import Process


def initializer():
    print("Before sqlite connect")
    connection = sqlite3.connect("/tmp/files.db")

    print("Before sqlite cursor")
    connection.cursor()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    response = requests.get("http://google.com")

    init_process = Process(target=initializer)
    init_process.start()
    init_process.join()

    print("Exit code: %d" % init_process.exitcode)
```

The process crashes before I can create the cursor:

```
 % python3 file-scanner.py
Before sqlite connect
Exit code: -11
```

It only happens on Python 3 on OS X it seems. And *only* happens if I use `requests` before connecting to sqlite.

I don't have the opportunity to switch to Python 2 -- nor do I really want to.

Comment: tried changing to a weird filename which no one could mess with  in `/tmp`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried this as well. Changing the db name to `"hello.db"` in the local folder, then `rm -f hello.db && python3 file-scanner.py`. Also tried in `/tmp`. Same issue unfortunately.

Comment: The same code works for me in both Python2 and Python3, Another step could be to note down the modified time of your "db file" before running your script and after running your script. Also note down the time without requests when you can connect to it.